# Visio VBA: How to register to mouse double click event on a shape in VB code

Tags: vba, visio

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to change the shape's ShapeSheet (spreadsheet) parameters via a VBA code? More precisely, I need to change the EventDblClick parameter value in the shape's ShapeSheet.
2. Is there another way to register a mouse double click event handler to a Visio shape? I want that a subroutine I provide will be called every time the shape is double clicked and to get the shape object as parameter.

What I know to do so far is to register to add shape event like this:

Private Sub Document_ShapeAdded(ByVal vsoShape As Visio.IVShape)

```
 'Do something with the shape object.
```

End Sub

This subroutine is called every time a new shape is added to the Visio page.

Answer (score 2):

Using [this link](http://guides.wmlcloud.com/office/Microsoft-Visio-2010---Introducing-Automation-and-VBA-Code-(part-3)---Calling-VBA-Code-from-a-SmartShape-.aspx) as a guide:

Your setup for a subroutine is good, and in this case leaving it `Private` will work because it is referenced within the same document.  If your shape is calling a subroutine in another document or Office product, you would need to make the referenced subroutine `Public`.

When you drop the new shape, define it and name it first. Then, you can set the double-click subroutine like this:

```
shpYourShapeName.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, _
    visRowEvent, visEvtCellDblClick).FormulaU = _
    "CALLTHIS(""ThisDocument.SubRoutineName"")"
```

Where "SubRoutineName" is the public subroutine contained in the VBA code for the drawing.

Comment: You will also have to pass a reference to the shape object in your function call.

Comment: Great, thanks! 
This actually works!
However, it still works even if the "SubRoutineName" is define as private.

Comment: @Dudi72 Good to know, thanks. I know that's not the case in other VBA subroutine calls (reports calling form subs in Access, for example), so I'll chalk it up to inconsistency across products. I'll edit my answer to say "might".

Comment: @Dudi72 Also, you're welcome! If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please [mark the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as the solution (and upvote if you feel appropriate), so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. Thanks!